# Custom commands in user-extensions.js fail to load when starting Selenium RC

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I'm using Selenium IDE to create some tests. In the options of the IDE i have specified an user-extensions.js file which is working as expected. Here are its contents:

```
Selenium.prototype.doactivateEnv = function(nomDeVariable){
    storedVars[nomDeVariable] = "test";
}
```

When I start a test that uses the "activateEnv" command it runs perfectly fine, executing it and having the expected behaviour.
On the otherhand, when I start a Selenium RC server it completely fails to recognize the existence of this command. All my tests fail with the same error:

```
info: Starting test /selenium-server/tests/TestStaticID.html
info: Executing: |activateEnv | ENV |  |
error: Unknown command: 'activateEnv'
warn: currentTest.recordFailure: Unknown command: 'activateEnv'
```

This is what I use to start the selenium RC server:

```
D:\__Miroslav\OMC\tests>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar 
-userExtensions user-extensions.js -port 4545 -htmlsuite *chrome 
"http://localhost:8080/" TestSuite\tests.html results\results.html
```

The user-extensions.js is in the same folder as the server's jar file, I have tried with and w/o absolute path to the file, it doesn't make any difference.
Also, I have tried with Firefox, Chrome and IE, all of them fail in the same way.

I feel that I'm missing something very very basic and stupid, but I just can't seem to find it.
Any help will be appriciated.

EDIT: I just tested it and if I load the Selenium RC in interactive mode with user Extensions enabled, it works fine:

```
14:47:31.531 INFO - Command request: activateEnv[ENV, ] on session 887e2d2c6f884c81b0c39f32c24d523a
14:47:31.531 INFO - Got result: OK on session 887e2d2c6f884c81b0c39f32c24d523a
```

Still not working in -htmlsuite mode.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have no idea how and why, but it suddenly works now :-/
I've been toying with setting up FirefoxProfile for the selenium (mostly following this tutorial: [this tutorial](http://girliemangalo.wordpress.com/2009/02/05/creating-firefox-profile-for-your-selenium-rc-tests/)) and at some point I just noticed that it has suddenly started passing the tests, that previously failed because of the "Unknown command" defined in my user-extensions.js

I really have no idea what triggered it. At first I was thinking it was the fact that there is a special profile, then I noticed that I have moved around a little bit the arguments to selenium-server and at first the example that I cited here did not work, but as I was troubleshooting, trying to find what is the cause by removing, changing and adding arguments in the end just everything magically worked.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar -port 4545 -userExtensions user-extensions.js -firefoxProfileTemplate FFProfileSelenium -htmlsuite *firefox http://localhost:8080 testSuite\tests.html testSuite\results.html
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar -port 4545 -userExtensions user-extensions.js -htmlsuite *firefox http://localhost:8080 testSuite\tests.html testSuite\results.html
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar -port 4545 -userExtensions user-extensions.js -htmlsuite *firefox http://localhost:8080/ TestSuite\tests.html results\results.html
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar -userExtensions user-extensions.js -port 4545 -htmlsuite *chrome "http://localhost:8080/" TestSuite\tests.html results\results.html
```

At first only the first two of these commands were working, and the other two failed, but as I said, while I was trying to find the reason why they failed, they started working. Now all of that executes perfectly.
I'm not at all satisfied with this answer, but at least it works now :-/

Answer (score 1):

From the past:

When it opens and hangs, hit Ctrl-Shift-J and see what crops up.  For me, it's a problem in my user-extensions.js file, but it might be different for you.